# Does taking the Domain Initiate cleric feat a second time give a second focus point?

Tags: spells, feats, pathfinder-2e, spell-slots

Under Focus Points from Multiple Sources the book reads:

> It’s possible, especially through archetypes, to gain focus spells and Focus Points from more than one source. If this happens, you have just one focus pool, adding all the Focus Points together to determine the total size of your pool. (Remember that the maximum number of Focus Points a pool can have is 3.) If you have multiple abilities that give you a focus pool, each one adds 1 Focus Point to your pool. (Core Rulebook pg. 302)

It's not clear to me if taking the same feat multiple times counts as more than one source, or multiple abilities, for the sake of getting an additional focus point. Specifically, the Domain Initiate cleric feat doesn't seem to mention anything on the issue.

The Domain Initiate cleric feat reads:

> **Special** You can select this feat multiple times, selecting a different domain each time and gaining its domain spell. (Core Rulebook pg. 121)

Comment: My book does not say that on pg. 300, nor can I find that in errata.

Comment: You're right, I got the page number wrong. It's 302. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Oh, yes. I retracted my answer as incomplete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No, but higher-level class feats can

The [Focus Spells](http://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=276) rules (CRB 300) state:

> You automatically gain a focus pool of 1 Focus Point the first time you gain an ability that gives you a focus spell.

The key phrase here is "the first time" for two reasons:

- It specifies when you initially gain a focus point (when you first take the [Domain Initiate](http://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=265) feat, in your case)
- It specifies that you gain a focus point from this source only the **first time** you gain this ability

So no, taking Domain Initiate two or more times will not grant you additional focus points beyond the first (though it will give you access to more focus spells to use with that focus point).

### How can I get more focus points?

This is where other class feats come into play. Consider [Advanced Domain](http://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=285), an eighth-level cleric class feat:

> Your studies or prayers have unlocked deeper secrets of your deity’s domain. You gain an advanced domain spell from one of your domains. **Increase the number of Focus Points in your focus pool by 1.**

*(Emphasis mine)*

### What about through archetypes or multiclassing?

You can get more focus points from later taking other distinct feats or abilities that explicitly grant a focus pool according to this clause from the [Focus Points from Multiple Sources](http://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=276) sidebar (CRB 302):

> If you have multiple abilities that give you a focus pool, each one adds 1 Focus Point to your pool.

A low-level example of this is the first-level monk class feat [Ki Rush](http://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=432), which includes the following:

> You gain the ki rush ki spell and a focus pool of 1 Focus Point.

You already have a focus pool granted to you by the [Focus Spells](http://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=276) rules (because you received a focus spell from Domain Initiate). The [Focus Points from Multiple Sources](http://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=276) rules clarify what happens when you get additional abilities that grant a focus pool/point:

> If this happens, you have just one focus pool, adding all the Focus Points together to determine the total size of your pool.

If you had a character with Domain Initiate and a focus pool of 1 point, and that character later somehow took Ki Rush, then you would have a focus pool of 2 points.

Comment: Could you address the line "If you have multiple abilities that give you a focus pool, each one adds 1 Focus Point to your pool." more directly? Also, the "first time" phrase doesn't say "only the first time" like you suggest in one of your bullet points; I think you should justify that a bit more.

Comment: @Daryl Bagley I expanded on my answer in response to the first part of your comment. The second part stands; if you take Domain Initiate twice, you are not fulfilling the "first time you gain an ability" requirement to gain another focus pool. I'd argue that the "first time" refers to only the first time you gain **any** ability to cast a focus spell. Otherwise the clause within some abilities that grants a focus pool/point would be redundant.