# How can I increase the size of a Focus Pool with a non-class feat?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, focus-pool

Is there a way beside Human -> Multitalented -> Psychic Dedication to increase a Focus Point pool witout spending a class feat? It is good, but comes a bit late at level 9.

Comment: Are you looking for an increase in the size of your Focus Point pool, or just ways to restore Focus Points? The title implies one way, but the body of the question implies another.

Comment: @ESCE I want to increase the pool, so I can take the X Focus feat to regain 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Natural Ambition

If you're looking for a true focus pool increase, [Natural Ambition](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=70) is available starting at level 1 for Humans. It's easily obtainable by level 5 for non-Humans via [Adopted Ancestry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=751) (Humans) as a level 3 General Feat, then Natural Ambition as a level 5 Ancestry Feat. The following classes can get an extra Focus Point in their pool at level 1. Basically, any class that has either a Focus Point innately and a level 1 feat that grants another Focus Spell (e.g. Bard), or has two Focus Point granting feats available to them at level 1 (e.g. Monk):

- Bard (via Hymn of Healing or Lingering Composition)
- Cleric* (Cloistered only, via Domain Initiate a second time, dependent on GM interpretation of multiple sources/abilities - see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/170130/does-taking-the-domain-initiate-cleric-feat-a-second-time-give-a-second-focus-po/170155#170155))
- Monk (via Ki Strike and Ki Rush)
- Ranger* (sorta, via Gravity Weapon and Heal Companion, if you already have an animal companion through some other means which is pretty unlikely)
- Summoner (via Extend Boost)
- Witch (via Cackle)
- Arguably... Wizard (there's a reading of the rules that would have Universalist Wizards start with one Focus Point, and then gain another by taking Hand of the Apprentice. I strongly disagree with this reading, but your GM might not).

Comment: You do not get a 2nd Focus Point from [Deity's Domain](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/199398/9552) unless you got it through multiclass and the second [Domain Initiate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/170155/9552)

Comment: @András good spot... I should know given I have an answer on that linked question too . Fixed

Comment: The second link shows that a second Domain Initiate does not increase the Focus Pool.

Comment: @András added link to question and caveat - I could see some tables interpreting that differently. The Focus Point rules are a little bit of a mess as it is. Did call it out though, since it's important to note that won't work at all tables; that was a good spot on your part.

Comment: if you don't agree with the only, accepted answer there, you should give another

Answer (score 3):

## It takes 2 *rare* ancestry feats

If you have access to and take [Fey Influence](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1239) on level 5 and [Glamour](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=4050) on 13, you get 1 Focus Point.

Both are rather weak, Multitalented + Psychic Dedication is much more freqently useful for the price, even if you have to get Adopted Ancestry for it.